# How to generate a new and second Google Maps API key for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to generate a new API key for my android application. But when I follow the steps on http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html it always gives me the same key. I think there is something wrong with my old key. How can I get a different and new one?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Creating API key for MAP

For debug mode:

1.in cmd direct the path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin>

2.paste the following keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "c:\users\pradeep.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

3.copy the MD5 fingerprint and go to the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup  , copy the fingerprint to the box and check the check box hit the button..

4.Thats it API key for debug mode was generated.

5.Copy the AP key in the XML file where u have to give api key and run the app.

For Release mode:

1.Generate a keystore using eclipse

```
i.Right click the project and android tools-> Export signed application package -> hit next and create a new keystore( Choose a location to store it and don't forget the location . its important).

ii.choose a location and keystore name and password,press next, and give alias name and password for that ,peroid and name and choose the destination file where to store the .apk file and press finish.
```

2.follow the same steps which for the debug mode . the only difference is in the second step that the path we will enter should be the above keystore path(replace this path c:\users\pradeep.android\debug.keystore to the created path). thats it.

3.do the other steps as follows. over.....

load the signed apk file to your android device ,and check the map part

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a newly generated key?  If the key signature is different than the existing one, it should give you a different API key.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean with the newly generated key? I always get the same MD5 fingerprint and it naturally it gives me always the same api key.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know API keys follow the 1 key per domain rule.
Please go through the links below, maybe they will help.
[http://drupal.org/node/183021](http://drupal.org/project/keys)
 and http://drupal.org/project/keys

Comment: Map keys for android application are a bit different :-)

Comment: but woudnt the concept of one key per domain be the same?

Comment: no :-) because its 1 key per application. Domain has nothing to do with this.