# Obtaining Android Public Map API Key

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been trying to obtain a public map api key for my Android app. However the public key that I receive from Google does not work.

I have been using the following steps:

---

Obtaining Release Public Map API Key

1.Obtain Private Key:

- Use Export of Eclipse to sign release application and create new keystore

2.Obtain MD5 certificate:

- using alias and keystore set up
- use keytool in Java directory: keytool -list -alias poly_alias -keystore
- copy MD5 certificate

3.Obtain API Map Key:

- Visit http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html and enter MD5 certificate
- copy key

4.Use New Map API Key:

- insert new map key for string in strings.xml for string mapApiKey

---

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try the steps which is in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597534/how-to-generate-a-new-and-second-google-maps-api-key-for-android/15520295#15520295

Answer (score 1):

You were sketchy on the last step, so you may want to look at the final two steps on this page:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#finalsteps.

If it still doesn't work, you may want to explain what is happening, and change the values, but you may want to show an example of one of your layout files and the android manifest, to see if you may have made a typo or something.

Answer (score 0):

You are following instructions for using the release signing key. Make sure you are building your APK in release mode. Normally, you build in debug mode and would use a Maps API key based on the debug signing key.

Comment: "Use Export of Eclipse to sign release application and create new keystore" - when i use eclipse am i in release mode. I have signed the application and created a keystore, I create a certificate fingerprint and get the corresponding key, however when i try to use the key that Google provides me it doesn't work. My debug key works for me but no the release key. Please help