# Google API public key

Tags: android, google-maps

I am currently using the developer key for the Google API. How can you acquire a public key?

Is there any free license or a limited number of hits?

Comment: google map api is free only and there is no limitations like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a GoogleMaps key just follow these steps:

https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#finalsteps

Also please use the search function!:
[Obtaining Android Public Map API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462044/obtaining-android-public-map-api-key)

Comment: @marceloamx Yes it is. Make sure you use your release.keystore and not debug.keystore

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/apiKey.html

useful link 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey
https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey?hl=sv-SE#getdebugfingerprint

**as you need the different key for each siging key so not forgot to get the different signing key for emulator as it has different key**

http://blogspot.fluidnewmedia.com/2009/04/displaying-google-maps-in-the-android-emulator/

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android