# Obtaining Google map API key

Tags: android, google-maps

i have obtained the MD5 fingerprint by using the following steps.
1.Obtain Private Key:

> Use Export of Eclipse to sign release application and create new keystore

2.Obtain MD5 certificate:

> using alias and keystore set up

But whenever i tried to generate API key from "http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html" it always says 
"The fingerprint you entered is not valid.Enter a valid certificate fingerprint"

i cross checked MD5 fingerprint again and again, but it didn't work. Help me Please.

Comment: i got the answer its [here][1]. check this out.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1/7140636#7140636

Comment: see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597534/how-to-generate-a-new-and-second-google-maps-api-key-for-android/15520295#15520295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it was outputting SHA1 certificate and i needed MD5. I have given the solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1/7140636#7140636).